# Iterating a huge list causes gc overhead limit exceeded

Tags: scala, apache-spark, garbage-collection

I have a very big file. For each bigram (two-word) for each line of the file I have to check the whole file. What I have done in scala is obviously wrong, but I have no idea how to fix it.

This function returns all lines of the file (around 3 millions!)

```
def allSentences() : ArrayList[String] = {
      val res: ArrayList[String] = new ArrayList[String]()
      val filename = "/path/test.txt"
      val fstream: FileInputStream = new FileInputStream(filename)
      val br: BufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(fstream))
      var strLine: String = null
      while ({strLine = br.readLine();  strLine!= null})
        res.add(strLine)
      br.close()
      return res
   }
```

And this is how I use it:

```
val p = sc.textFile("file:///path/test.txt")
val result11 = p
           .flatMap(line => biTuple(line))
           .map(word => (word, 1))
           .reduceByKey(_ + _)

          val result10 = result11
            .flatMap { tuple => allSentences().map(tuple._1 -> _) }
            .map(tuple => (tuple._1, count10(tuple._1,tuple._2)))
            .reduceByKey(_ + _)
```

I'm almost sure the problem is here in `.flatMap { tuple => allSentences().map(tuple._1 -> _) }` but is there any other way to do it!?

P.S: `biTuple()` returns an `ArrayList` of all bigrams of the line. `count10()` returns 1 if the first word of bigram exists in line but the second doesn't. 
`result11` is an RDD of all bugrams and their counts like ("word1 word2", count)

This is the error output:

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:201)
        at org.apache.spark.serializer.DeserializationStream$$anon$2.getNext(Serializer.scala:198)
        at org.apache.spark.util.NextIterator.hasNext(NextIterator.scala:73)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$13.hasNext(Iterator.scala:371)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.util.CompletionIterator.hasNext(CompletionIterator.scala:32)
        at org.apache.spark.InterruptibleIterator.hasNext(InterruptibleIterator.scala:39)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalAppendOnlyMap.insertAll(ExternalAppendOnlyMap.scala:152)
        at org.apache.spark.Aggregator.combineCombinersByKey(Aggregator.scala:58)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.BlockStoreShuffleReader.read(BlockStoreShuffleReader.scala:83)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.ShuffledRDD.compute(ShuffledRDD.scala:98)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.MapPartitionsRDD.compute(MapPartitionsRDD.scala:38)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.computeOrReadCheckpoint(RDD.scala:306)
        at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD.iterator(RDD.scala:270)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:73)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:89)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:214)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

Note that I have `SPARK_WORKER_MEMORY=90G` and `SPARK_DRIVER_MEMORY=90G`.

Comment: Can you add the output error? We need to know if the GC is in the worker or in the driver.

Comment: Thanks @ThiagoBaldim I just added the output error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like what you are trying to do is a cartesian product of `result11` with `p` (your original list of sentences), but you're doing it by opening and reading the entire file into memory for every entry in `result11`.  That's bound to stress the garbage collector, although I can't say for sure that's the cause of the GC problem.  Spark has a `cartesian` method on RDDs, and if my interpretation of what you're trying to do is correct, it will probably work better.  (It will do a lot of data copying over the network, however.)

You also might investigate whether the `count10` logic should be used in a filter operation, reducing the number of entries that need to be handled by the final `reduceByKey`.